# Return multiple times from a method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, return

I have a method that takes a while to complete. I would like my method to return a "preliminary" result before returning the "final" result.

I would like to understand if it is possible to something like this:

```
public Object myMethod () {
    /*some computation here*/

     return firstResult;

     /*
     very long computation here
     */

     return finalResult;
}
```

Is this even possible or can you suggest some kind of workaround?

Comment: Why don't you call the `myMethod ()` twice?As in at first take a variable make it false so that it dose not execute the second block of code,when you call it again, make it true.

Comment: You are expecting the unexpected behavior from a method.

Comment: Please clarify your question and give background information, such as does this involve a GUI? Android? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put the long-running task on an executor (which would execute the task asynchronously using a thread pool) and return a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) that you can use later to get the answer. When you call `get` on the future, it blocks until the task finishes, so you can use your initial answer right away and call `Future.get` when you need more precision later, having given the task some time to finish.

The return value might look like this:

```
class MyMethodReturnStuff {

    private Object quickAnswer;
    private Future longAnswer;
    private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    MyMethodReturnStuff(Object quickAnswer, Future longAnswer) {
        this.quickAnswer = quickAnswer;
        this.longAnswer = longAnswer;
    }

    Object getAnswer(long expectedDelay) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < expectedDelay ?
        quickAnswer : longAnswer.get();
    }
}
```

If you expect the long calculation to take 5 seconds, calling `getAnswer(5000)` would return the quick answer if less than 5 seconds has passed and would return the longAnswer otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you simply use two different methods?

```
public class Computer {

    private String commonVar1;
    private int commonVar2;

    public Object shortComput() {
        // short comput using commonVar1 and commonVar2
        return firstResult;
    }

    public Object longComput() {
        // long comput using commonVar1 and commonVar2
        return finalResult;
    }

}
```

When calling:

```
Computer c = new Computer();
Object firstResult = c.shortComput();
// do some short stuff with firstResult before launching:
Object finalResult = c.longComput();
```

Comment: However, `longComput` may have to redo calculations previously performed in `shortComput`, or rely on the assumption that the result wasn't changed in the meantime.

Comment: @WChargin Not if you store the results of the calculations in Computer's fields. And if the Computer instance can't by used by several threads at the same time, the results won't change.

Comment: @WChargin Yeah, this would then be the developer's intentional choice ;)

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible, a function can only return once. Once it returns subsequent code will not be executed. However you can change your code design to instead write the output into a data structure referenced by the argument / placed as a class member. For example:

```
public void longRunningFunc(List<String> output) {
  // some computation here
  output.add(..);

  // very long computation here
  output.add(..);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is the way to go.

If you're not familiar with `SwingWorker`, it's basically a class that lets you have long-running computations running.  They can give a result when they're done or publish interim results along the way, which is basically what you're trying to do.

From ["Tasks that Have Interim Results,"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) a section of the Java Tutorial:

> It is often useful for a background task to provide interim results while it is still working. The task can do this by invoking SwingWorker.publish. This method accepts a variable number of arguments. Each argument must be of the type specified by SwingWorker's second type parameter.

For [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/concurrency/FlipperProject/src/concurrency/Flipper.java):

```
private class FlipTask extends SwingWorker<Void, FlipPair> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        long heads = 0;
        long total = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            total++;
            if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                heads++;
            }
            // Here's your interim result, your "first return statement"
            publish(new FlipPair(heads, total));            
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<FlipPair> pairs) {
        FlipPair pair = pairs.get(pairs.size() - 1);
        headsText.setText(String.format("%d", pair.heads));
        totalText.setText(String.format("%d", pair.total));
        devText.setText(String.format("%.10g", 
                ((double) pair.heads)/((double) pair.total) - 0.5));
    }
}
```

If for some reason you can't use `SwingWorker`, you'd need to use asynchronous threads to do this. You could try something like:

```
interface Callback {
    public void computationComplete(Result r);
}
public Result doComputation(final Callback c) {
    // Do computation
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Complete computation
            c.computationComplete(finalResult);
        }
    }).start();
    return firstResult;
}
```

but this is basically reinventing the wheel.

Comment: How do we know that this question involves Swing?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a listener pattern.  A custom listener instance can be passed into the method or added to the object.  As the long-running method executes, you can call the listener as appropriate passing whatever infomation you need.  This listener can be called many times.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not possible in Java. Why don't you simply split your method in two different ones?

Comment: This is definitely possible in Java !

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a condition:

```
public class TestMethod {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
boolean yes=false;
int something=compute(yes);
System.out.println(something);
yes=true;
something=compute(yes);
System.out.println(something);
}

public static int compute(boolean yes)
{
if(!yes)
{
    System.out.println("1st block");
return 22;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("2nd block");
return 33;
}

}
}
```

**EDIT :**
I have used a single method as per the question : Return multiple times from a method.

Comment: No. Instead of that you should have two methods. This is basically really wrong.

Comment: The code you have presented is really poorly designed. You use a static flag to pass some value to method that can be declared as argument. Future more you use that to split the logic. Same thing you would achieve declaring method1 and method2 and call them sequentially. This could be reduced to single large method (that is also bad). The conclusion is that your example do not solve the problem and make the code less readable.

Comment: @Vash I think you havn't read the question carefully."_a method_" That is why used a single method ;)

Answer (score -2):

This is possible, but you will have to introduce to thread.

You application should have two threads `main` and `worker`.

The `main` thread, is your whole program. That during his work start the `worker`. Worker do the computation, after first part he can set a value that `main` thread can read and display.

Comment: i.e., use a `SwingWorker`; why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You still haven't shown how `one` method can return `two` results :/

Comment: @WChargin: how do we know that his problem involves a Swing GUI? I may have missed something, but I don't see mention of this in the original question. The correct general answer is to use a Future as per Nathan's answer (1+). That's what a SwingWorker does anyway.

Comment: @A4L One method *can't* return two results. The means that the OP is suggesting is not possible. But his *end goal* is achievable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Interesting point; I didn't know about `Future`. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @WChargin: yep, have a look at it. If you look at the SwingWorker API, you'll see that it implements the `Future<T>` interface.

Comment: @A4L, I have. You did not got it. You have focused on the return. The goal is to pass the information between one piece of method and another. OP expressed this as return. Having two threads one can communicate with another returning him status about his progress. And this can be expressed as multiple return. As method is atomic we can return only once from it but in different points.

Comment: "This is definitely possible in Java !" this comment (to an answer that tells that this is not possible and gives a workaround) clearly says it is.

Comment: @Vash also OP has to take take pain of locking and unlocking threads.You cannot execute both things at the same time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, The problem might not be related with Swing. But that class is delivered by platform in rt. Same thing was in C# class was called once GUIWorker but it was so perfect that was renamed (and relocated ) to BacgroundWorker. Having that Swing might be a salt in the eye. But for sure will perform as expected, implementing interface like `Future` is more complicated that looks.

Comment: @A4L, To be purist. It is possible. But the code after first return will be dead. ;-).

Comment: @Vash: `"...implementing interface like Future is more complicated that looks."` What makes you say this? Using Futures is not all that complicated. What issues with their implementation are you referring to specifically?

Comment: @joeyrohan, you have absolutely right. That is why i did not wrote the code. It to vague to say what and when OP need and want. He has the tool now, only thing he need is to master it. ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, `Future` is only a delegate that provide some content. The hard part is the synchronization etc. If is given for free why not use it ? The decision about what is better FutureTask or SwingWorker is about the coder. What he prefer is the best ;->. The goal is to work ;-).